# Sort list of tuples by month python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of holidays in tuples:

```
holidays = [('Easter', ('Apr', 1), 0),
            ('Earth Day', ('Apr', 22), 0),
            ('Pearl Harbor Rememberance Day', ('Dec', 7), 0),
            ('Christmas Day', ('Dec', 25), 50),
            ('Groundhog Day', ('Feb', 2), 0)]
```

and a function to sort them:

```
def holiday1(holidays : [(str,(str,int),int)]) -> [(str,(str,int),int)]:
    return sorted(holidays, key=lambda x:x[1])
```

I sorted them by month in alphabetical order but I want to sort them by position of months. (e.g. Jan = 1, Feb = 2, etc.)

I have created a dictionary for the months:

```
months = {'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, 'Apr': 4, 'May': 5, 'Jun': 6, 'Jul': 7, 'Aug': 8, 'Sep': 9, 'Oct': 10, 'Nov': 11, 'Dec': 12}
```

I'm not sure how to use the dict 'months' to sort the list of tuples so that the outcome is:

```
holidays = [('Groundhog Day', ('Feb', 2), 0),
            ('Easter', ('Apr', 1), 0),
            ('Earth Day', ('Apr', 22), 0),
            ('Pearl Harbor Rememberance Day', ('Dec', 7), 0),
            ('Christmas Day', ('Dec', 25), 50)]
```

Comment: `key=lambda x: months[x[1][0]]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elements that we sort are 3-tuples where the second element is again a tuple. We are interested in the month, which is the *first* element of the *second* element of the tuple, so we can access that with `x[1][0]`. But of course we do not want to sort that alphabetically, but in the order of the months, so we can perform a lookup with `months[x[1][0]]`. So we can sort it only taking the *month* into account with:

```
# only taking month into account
return sorted(holidays, key=lambda x: months[x[1][0]])
```

But my guess is that in case of a *tie*, you want to take the day into account. The nice thing about tuples is that if you compare them, Python will first contain the first elements of the two tuples. In case of a tie, it will compare the second element of both tuples, etc. We can use this by letting the `key` return a 2-tuple: first the index of the month, followed by the day:

```
# taking month and day into account
return sorted(holidays, key=lambda x: (months[x[1][0]], x[1][1]))
```

**EDIT**: in case you want to sort the holidays by name if both the month and the day are equal, we can construct 3-tuples:

```
# taking month, day and name into account
return sorted(holidays, key=lambda x: (months[x[1][0]], x[1][1], x[0]))
```

Comment: Is it also possible to sort the string of holiday names in alphabetical order after taking in to account the already sorted months followed by days in the same return line? Thanks

Comment: @Jtseng526: sure, we can construct 3-tuples as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use a key function that ranks the object you want to sort.

```
def by_month(holiday):
    """sort by month, then day, then name of holiday"""
    holiday_name = holiday[0]
    month, day = holiday[1]
    month_value = months[month]
    return month_value, day, holiday_name

sorted(holidays, key=by_month)
```

The output would be

```
[('Groundhog Day', ('Feb', 2), 0),
 ('Easter', ('Apr', 1), 0),
 ('Earth Day', ('Apr', 22), 0),
 ('Pearl Harbor Rememberance Day', ('Dec', 7), 0),
 ('Christmas Day', ('Dec', 25), 50)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ad-hoc data structures and values to represent a holiday, define types whose values behave correctly.

First, create a dedicated type for months, instead of just using regular strings.

```
from enum import IntEnum, auto, unique, EnumMeta

Month = IntEnum('Month',
        "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec".split())
```

Next, define a class to represent a holiday, instead of using plain tuples.

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Holiday:
    def __init__(self, name, month, day, x):
        self.name = name
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self.x = x
        self.sort_key = (self.month, self.day, self.name)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.sort_key < other.sort_key

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.sort_key == other.sort_key and self.x == other.x

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ({} {})".format(self.name, self.month._name_, self.day)
```

Now your holidays are sortable without any further effort:

```
holidays = [
    Holiday('Easter', Month.Apr, 1, 0),
    Holiday('Earth Day', Month.Apr, 22, 0),
    Holiday('Pearl Harbor Rememberance Day', Month.Dec, 7, 0),
    Holiday('Christmas Day', Month.Dec, 25, 50),
    Holiday('Groundhog Day', Month.Feb, 2, 0)
    ]

for h in sorted(holidays):
    print(h)
```

outputs

```
Groundhog Day (Feb 2)
Easter (Apr 1)
Earth Day (Apr 22)
Pearl Harbor Rememberance Day (Dec 7)
Christmas Day (Dec 25)
```